# What is the best (free) Font Explorer for Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts

I am looking for an alternative to my old "Font Navigator" that I... borrowed... from the CorelDraw Suite :-)

Googling for it, took me to hundreds of pages with old software, so I hope to find a quick idea from here (waiting for FontExplorer X from Linotype).

Which Font Explorer for Windows do you currently use? 
My "requisites" are:

- browse and preview installed/uninstalled fonts
- install/uninstall fonts
- free :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This [thread](http://typophile.com/node/41998) references the main font explorers like [Bitstream Font Navigator](http://www.bitstream.com/fonts/index.html), [Typograf](http://www.neuber.com/typograph/) (both already mentioned) and [OT1 Font Manager](http://www.ot1fontmanager.com/en/)

... but they are not free.

The only one which *might* be free would be [Font Explorer X](http://www.linotype.com/2629/fontexplorerxfeatures.html), which has a [beta version for PC](http://fex.linotype.com/download/pc/FontExplorerX-0.9.1.2250.exe), but that version is quite "dangerous"

> “It IS very glitchy. Not totally useless but you have to get over the fact that it totally messes up any directory of fonts. So make a seperate folder for the fonts you want to import into the program as it will delete those fonts from the original folder. Also make a backup copy of your windows fonts folder just in case it decides to remove the fonts from there too.”

Comment: I am waiting FontExplorer X, which has exited beta phase some months ago. But in the meantime, I would like to experiment with other products :-)

Comment: I understand: I hope you will find the right product from the other answers. Let us know ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found Opcion quite practical.  Works on multiple platforms.

Doesn't do install/uninstall, but does everything else.

http://opcion.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I had tried a lot over the years. The one I currently use is [AMP Font Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php), which is very good and does all you request... and more (like "Install font temporarily", manage categories, etc.).

[Arjan Mel's Font Viewer](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22arjan+mel%22"Arjan Mel's Font Viewer") is also good but old, abandoned and a bit unstable...

Plus I have various character table viewers, including the superb [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html).

Comment: AMP Font Viewer looks really good, but I don't see the possibility to see subdirectories for non-installed fonts (I have to navigate to see them). Am I missing something? 
Thanks a lot for the progeam suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Start->Run->Fonts

Works for me (:

You can uninstall, preview and add new fonts. It also displays the font type.

It's a redirect to WINDOWSDIR\Fonts